# unable to send emails from smtp.office365, website hosted on plesk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, office365, plesk

I'm using PLESK web hosting website.
For the SMTP I'm using smtp.office365.com with port 587
the website is developed using asp.net MVC application
I'm getting this error : Unable to connect to the remote server.
Note: locally I can send emails successfully using the same settings.
is there's any configuration I should enable on PLESK in order to able to send emails from this SMTP: smtp.office365.com ?
I tried changing the password
Also tried whitelisting the IP address